# Why my relay is so slow?

Tags: relays, bandwidth

I have a connection of 100mb/s and its going too slow, just look here: https://globe.torproject.org/#/search/query=A11BAE8F2676FF78727EE74949836E495D801D90

The relay is located in a OVH VPS

How can I use the complete bandwidth?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this maillist: https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2012-August/025296.html

This is Edward Snowden.

> Hi guys,
>
> I've been running a kind-of 1gbps (voxility style 1gbps) exit server
>   on  Debian for a couple months, and while it started out very fast,
>   it's  gotten much slower over time. ....

He used 1gbps, it is 10x more than your speed. Anyway, his tuning shall help you.

```
*sysctl* (straight c&p [minus the nf_conntrack entries] from Moritz' 
excellent guide.  nf_conntrack is not currently used on my server):

net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 33554432
net.core.rmem_default = 524287
net.core.wmem_default = 524287
net.core.optmem_max = 524287
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 300000
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 33554432 33554432 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 30000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 300000
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 4
vm.min_free_kbytes = 65536

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 3
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1025 65530
net.core.somaxconn = 30720
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 2000000
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you read [the lifecycle of a new tor relay](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay)?  In particular:

> So that's phase one: your new relay gets basically no use for the first few days of its life because of the low 20KB cap, while it waits for a threshold of bwauths to measure it.

Answer (score 1):

[TorServers.net](https://TorServers.net)  has an excellent [wiki entry on setting up exit relays](https://www.torservers.net/wiki/setup/server). I'll write some additional hints below:

1. You should make sure that you have a "real" 100MB/s connection. Several providers tell you that your server uses such a connection, but share it among several servers. So you won't reach the full 100MB/s.
2. In the case of OVH you should be aware that they accept Tor relays, but claim to eventually shut them down (probably when they notice abuse, see [GoodBadISPs at Tor's wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/GoodBadISPs#France). Currently your relay is listed as a non-exit, so everything should be fine.
3. According to the Globe page, your relay is only two days old. It takes some time until it reaches the full bandwidth.
4. Setting the `DirPort` option and thus sharing directory data might help to attract more bandwidth.
5. If you have a system with multiple cores, it is recommended to set up one Tor process per core. This uses more bandwidth and utilizes the CPUs better. See the TorServers wiki entry above.